# Jwt Authentication doesn't work in Blazor Serverside

Tags: asp.net-identity, jwt, blazor-server-side

I used Jwt authentication in a Blazor Client Hosted project with roles and everything (using Identity), But when I do the same thing in Blazor Server side It doesn't work, For example After I set the token in the Header:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {Model.Token}");                
            Console.WriteLine($"Is authenticated = {httpContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated}");
```

IsAuthenticated returns false, and when I navigate to home page (to cause a refresh) the IsAuthenticated still returns false and No user name is accessible through HttpContext.User.Identity.Name!! Is there a workaround for this. (the default authentication in Blazor serverside preview 6 is limited for Localization and other things and I don't want to use it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve my problem without a cookie or header, I created an Auth Class with username, isauthenticated and roles and method IsInRole in it and then injected (as singleton) this class to every view that use or populate this class and then populate it on success login (I used Identity checkpasswordsigninasync) I populate this class and use it through application, On Logout I simply create an empty Instance. 
I think because everything runs on the server this class is safe and its only limitation is that on page refresh authentication is lost and HttpContext.User is empty.

**EDIT**:

firstly, on Refresh the singleton services does not loose their data so Authentication Model does not empty.

Second: If you feel this Auth Model Makes programming unfamiliar, I could set ClaimPrincipal on login using an IEnumerable<Claim> -claims variable- like this:

```
httpContext.HttpContext.User = new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));
```

then use Intuitive HttpContext.User.IsInRole and HttpContext.User.Identity.Name like we did in Web Forms.

Comment: A strange workaround, but it may be useful to some. But note that fropm preview6 on we have a built-in authentication for server-side.

Comment: Since I use a Localization system without a route parameter or query string and that it works without a page refresh, I can't use this Localization with built in Blazor Authentication, So I decided to temporarily use a form of custom authentication , Until maybe in the future that custom authentication is supported in Blazor Serverside.